# Pulp error - 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'actualSolve'

Tags: python, pulp

I installed Pulp and GLPk via conda.

For `p.listSolvers(onlyAvailable=True)`, I see gurobi and mosek installed as solvers:

```
Restricted license - for non-production use only - expires 2022-01-13
No parameters matching '_test' found
['GUROBI', 'MOSEK']
```

But when doing .solve(), I get the following error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-5a6ec0364643> in <module>
----> 1 m.solve()

~/anaconda3/anaconda3/envs/isye6669/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pulp/pulp.py in solve(self, solver, **kwargs)
   1735         #time it
   1736         self.solutionTime = -clock()
-> 1737         status = solver.actualSolve(self, **kwargs)
   1738         self.solutionTime += clock()
   1739         self.restoreObjective(wasNone, dummyVar)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'actualSolve'
```

Versions of pulp = 2.4, python = 3.8.8, and glpk = 4.65

Comment: Did you use this command to install pulp `conda install -c conda-forge pulp` ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the solver you want to use. If you don't provide a solver as argument to the m.solve() method, pulp will use the default. In your case, the default solver is not available. Try providing a GUROBI() or MOSEK() solver to the solve method, as explained here:
https://coin-or.github.io/pulp/guides/how_to_configure_solvers.html

For example:

```
import pulp as pl
model = pl.LpProblem("Example", pl.LpMinimize)
solver = pl.GUROBI()
_var = pl.LpVariable('a')
_var2 = pl.LpVariable('a2')
model += _var + _var2 == 1
result = model.solve(solver)
```